# Wordpress site fails to run after migration via FTP to AWS EC2 Ubuntu with Apache2

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, migration

I am trying to manually migrate a Wordpress site via FTP to an AWS EC2 instance that runs an Ubuntu 20.04. Due to certain circumstances I cannot use plugins to do the migration. I basically copied the files of the site to the `/var/www/my_site` folder, and dumped its old database into a new one that I have access to, while setting up Apache2 as a web server.

And even though I tried almost every angle I could think of, the site does not run. Apache2 is able to run some of the initial files, including `wp-config.php`, but it fails somewhere along the line, and in the `wp-blog-header.php` file the `wp()` function fails when it gets called, or it doesn't even gets called.
When running in a browser, the HTTP request 301 redirects to a HTTPS request and it fails premanently. However, there is no indication in the code that a 301 redirect is set anywhere.

The odd things are that with basically the same configuration I am able to run a simple Wordpress installation on the EC2 instance, and the site I am migrating runs on my local Windows 10 environment with XAMPP. On the EC2 instance the site also fails with NginX.

The things I thought that might be variables in configuration are the following:

#### File and directory ownership

The owner of everything in the web root directory is `www-data`, and changing permissions of files and directories doesn't change the result, I have tried every variation.

#### Modules

Modules that are not enabled by default in Apache2 and needed by Wordpress are enabled, like php7.4, rewrite, expire and header.

#### Apache2 Virtualhost configuration

I took out ServerName and ServerAlias, because right now I am only trying to access the site throught the EC2 instance's IP address. Remember, that the same configuration (apart from the root directory) works for a simple Wordpress installation.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my_site
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<Directory  /var/www/my_site/>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

#### .htaccess files

The main .htaccess file in the project root again is the same as the simple Wordpress installation's.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|php|txt|xml|js|css)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# BEGIN Expire headers
  ExpiresActive On
 
  # Images
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
 
  # Video
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/mpeg "access plus 1 year"
 
  # CSS, JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 
  # Others
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
# END Expire headers
Header unset ETag
  FileETag None
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

However, there were some other .htaccess files elsewhere in other directories. In the wp-includes directory the .htaccess file looked like below, so I removed it.

```
<Files *.php>
deny from all
</Files>
<Files wp-tinymce.php>
allow from all
</Files>
<Files ms-files.php>
allow from all
</Files>
```

The other .htaccess files are in different plugin folders, and they don't seem to have any harmful directives.

#### Database configuration

There are some fields in the database `jsdl_options` table (in other installation the table name might be `wp_options`) that need to be set in order for the site to properly function. I also tried many variations, but this is the one that should be good according to other sources, and again, it works for the simple Wordpress installation.

```
site_url - http://<EC2 instance IP>
home - http://<EC2 instance IP>
upload_path - wp-content/uploads, but full path doesn't work either
```

#### wp-config.php

The `wp-config.php` file is seemingly properly configured. The site manages to connect to the database, it finds the cache location, and finishes reading the file without any issues.

```
define('WP_CACHE', true);
define( 'WPCACHEHOME', '/var/www/my_site/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/' );
define( 'DB_NAME', 'db' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'dbu' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'dbp' );
define( 'DB_HOST', 'dbh' );
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
(...)
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
define('FS_CHMOD_DIR',0755);
define('FS_CHMOD_FILE',0644);
define('WP_TEMP_DIR',dirname(__FILE__).'/wp-content/uploads');
(...)
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define ('WP_DEBUG_LOG', '/var/www/my_site/wp-errors.log' );
(...)
```

#### Logging

At this level, logging does not help anything. Apache2's debug-level logging does not provide additional information neither in the `error.log` nor in the `access.log` files. And the Wordpress logging only catches some unrelated PHP warnings.

#### Theories

My first theory is that something is blocking access to some internal (e.g. in `wp-includes`) files.

The other theory is that somewhere along the line there is an SSL configuration, that makes the site not run with simple HTTP requests, and requires HTTPS. But being able to run the site locally proves this otherwise.

So my questions are: Why does the site not run? Why does it fail midway during initialization? Why did it not fail in my local environment?

Comment: When you say things like _“and in the wp-blog-header.php file the wp() function fails when it gets called”_, what exactly does “fail” mean then? If you are not getting any errors - how exactly does “failure” manifest itself then?

Comment: WP still stores absolute URLs for the most part, not only in the configuration, but wherever the content contains references to media files, etc. With `http://<EC2 instance IP>`, I am assuming you accessed the site with a proper host name before, or at least a different IP? Then I would really recommend that you _do_ use a migration plugin, that can fix any such URLs stored anywhere in the database, just to be sure you don’t get any side effects from that. WP Migrate DB can do this for you, and you don’t have to run it on the target system, it will work from the old (or local) version as well.